# Is "${PS1-}" valid syntax and how does it differ from plain "$PS1"?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, variable-substitution, bourne-shell

I am looking at a script that has:

```
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
```

That trailing `-` bugs me a bit because it doesn't seem to Posix or Bash standard syntax. It this some arcane syntax that has been around forever, or is it a typo? Any references to standards / docs would be appreciated.

Normally I would code it:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
```

Which is more correct or is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is definitely [POSIX syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02). Paraphrasing:

Using `${parameter-word}`, if `parameter` is

- set and not null, then substitute the value of `parameter`,
- set but null, then substitute null, and
- unset, then substitute `word`.

Example session:

```
$ echo "${parameter-word}"
word
$ parameter=
$ echo "${parameter-word}"

$ parameter=value
$ echo "${parameter-word}"
value
```

"Null" here simply means the empty string. There is no special null value in POSIX shells, in contrast to SQL, for example.

This is also documented in the "Parameter Expansion" section of `man bash`.

Comment: I guess the bash and dash man-pages are incomplete, because they don't mention this syntax (odd)!

Comment: @Gregor Both manuals mention this. In the Bash manual it's in the paragraph before the list of parameter expansions, and in the Dash manual it's in the paragraph after.

Comment: OK, "Omitting the colon ...." I didn't see that :(

Comment: `zsh` is the only shell I know of that mentions the colon-free variants explicitly, rather than just making a note of what omitting the colon does.

Comment: Both the answer and `man bash` uses the term *null*, which is can be misleading. The correct term is *empty* (or *empty string* or *zero-length string*).

Comment: @pts, the text in POSIX pretty much exclusively uses the term "null", which might explain its use in the man pages.

Answer (score 28):

The variable expansion `${parameter:-word}` will use the value of `$parameter` if it's set and non-null (not an empty string), otherwise it will use the string `word`.

Omitting the `:` will not test if the value is empty, only whether it's unset or not.

This means that `${PS1-}` will expand to the value of `$PS1` if it's set, but to an empty string if it's empty or unset.  In this case, this is *exactly the same* as `${PS1:-}` as the string after `-` is also empty.

The difference between `"${PS1-}"` and `"$PS1"` is subtle, as @Rakesh Sharma notes: both will expand to the value of `$PS1`, or to an empty string if it is unset. The exception is when `set -u` is active, [in which case expanding unset variables would cause an error](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set). The (empty) default value set by`"${PS1-}"` circumvents this, expanding an unset `PS1` to the empty string without error.

[This is standard syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) ([originated in the Bourne shell in the late 70s](http://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/sh/)), as are a couple of other, similar expansions.

Comment: And since it was quoted, it's the same as `"$PS1"`, since if `PS1` is empty, it is empty, and the quotes keep the word from disappearing completely.

Comment: So long as the `set -u` is not in effect. When the nounset option is on, then "$PS1" => gives error. "${PS-}" won't.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax:

```
${parameter:-word}
```

and a special form:

```
${parameter-word}
```

is the [valid syntax in POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), means using the default value `word` if `parameter` is unset or null.

---

Normally, with `word` is empty, then:

```
${parameter-}
```

and:

```
$parameter
```

or:

```
${parameter}
```

are equivalent.

But under the effect of `set -u`, all unset variables cause the shell to be terminated. `${parameter-}` is used to bypass that strict rule. It works in both case so yes, it's more correct way.